# eclipse error mark still appears after fix

Tags: eclipse, error-handling

There was a library issue in a file and after fixing it, the red error mark in the line disappears. But the file, package and the project shows with red error mark.

I refreshed but still get the red mark. How to get those marks removed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different mechanisms for displaying problems in Eclipse. Annotations are a lightweight mechanism that are bound to an editor, and markers are used for displaying the problems anywhere else (e.g. Package explorer).

If the in-line annotation disappears, but the project error mark does not, it means, the annotations and markers became inconsistent. First you should try to save the files (sometimes the annotations gets removed during editing, while markers are only refreshed on save). Of course, you have already saved (else the refresh would not make any sense), so I guess, some markers got stuck.

To remove that marker, open the *Problems* view (Window/Open view), and find there the corresponding error marker, then remove it (Delete in the pop-up menu).